# Open VB6 File in VBA

Tags: vba, vb6

Can I import a file I made from VB6 to VBA? I tried it and it says it's not supported in VBE but I want to know if there's any other possible way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: What file (frm, bas, cls), are you trying to import. What are you trying to accomplish? Your question does not have enough information to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just import the raw VB6 code into VBA, no.

What you should be able to do is to create an ActiveX DLL with VB6. Referencing this DLL in your VBA project should allow you to invoke its exposed methods in VBA.